# string to wstring en c++

Tags: c++, linux, string

Utilizo esta función para pasar de std::string a std::wstring.

```
std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& str)
{
 size_t newsize = str.size() + 1;
 wchar_t * wcstring = new wchar_t[newsize];
 mbstowcs( wcstring,str.c_str(), newsize);
 std::wstring tocopy = wcstring;
 delete wcstring;
 return tocopy;
}
```

El problema que tengo es al recibir carácter ASCII extendidos, como por ejemplo la Ñ. ¿Cómo podría hacer esta transformación correctamente para ASCII extendido?, bajo linux.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema que tienes exactamente? ¿Te transforma o no te transforma la Ñ?

Comment: no transforma la Ñ

Comment: La `Ñ` **no existe** en la tabla ASCII, luego **no existe** un caracter que puedas transformar como tal. Otra cosa es que te movieses entre codificaciones que sí admiten ese caracter, como UTF-8 e [ISO-8859-1](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Comment: la Ñ es el caracter 209 en la tabla ASCII extendida, supongo que esta tabla también se le puede llamar ISO Latin-1 o ISO-8859-1. El caso es que en un string tengo una Ñ y quiero pasar ese string a wstring y la función mbstowcs no vale. Necesito alguna manera de hacer esto bajo linux en c++.

Comment: ASCII no es ASCII extendido. ASCII son 128 caracteres y ya, y eso es lo que usa `std::string`. La posición 209 es superior a 128 y no entra en un `char`, luego dificilmente va a poder aparecer en un `std::string`. Si tu intentas leer una `ñ` en `std::string` obtendrás una _secuencia rara_. Esa secuencia es cómo se define la `ñ` según la tabla que esté usando el dispositivo de entrada en ese momento. Dicho de otra forma, no hay una forma universal de identificar la `ñ` si este caracter no existe en la tabla en uso

Comment: Si hago un printf del string se imprime la Ñ sin problemas, por lo que el valor que me llega es interpretable como Ñ y esta "guardado" en un string, ¿no se puede pasar ese valor a wstring?.